# Pentaho Kettle: enter field mapping error?

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I'm working on a BI project and I'm facing a problem:
In Pentaho Kettle i put a table output and i established the connection with MySQL database, the connection is OK and i selected the specified table in target table. But when i click on Enter field mapping i get this error:

> Unable to close prepared statement after determining SQL layout
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1

I changed the MySQL connector jar file in Pentaho Library folder so i put `mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar` and i deleted the older one `mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar`, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to change your approach.  Try using "Generic database" as your Connection Type.

- Custom Connection URL

  jdbc:mysql://servername/db
- Custom Driver Class Name

  com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

And then username and password as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

the solution that worked was download the next version of mysql-connector-java 5-1.36 the following link http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

PDI version 5.4.x

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Download the lastest version of Mysql driver from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

I am using Pentaho BI Server Go to *./biserver-ce/tomcat/lib*  ; delete mysql-connector-java-x.x.x.jar and paste the new 
mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar

- Restart the BI pentaho server and it works.

[image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a249Q.png)

TAGS: PENTAHO , JOIN , ANSI_QUOTES, 'OPTION SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT' at line 1 , SQL_MODE